# Can I reach temperatures of 1400F In 2-4 Milliseconds With a 12 Gage Wire?

Tags: wire, pressure

I need a thicker, more sturdy wire that can put in a high PSI environment and still reach temperatures of 2-4 millisecond. The problems i see is thicker wire don't have as much resistance and a smaller mutil-twisted smaller wire. Is there away i can change that and still reach my desired temp of 1400F?